# Chrome does not register Service Worker in secure iFrame on insecure domain

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, iframe, https, service-worker

I have this [website](https://makefast-staging.app.baqend.com/) that registers a Service Worker to clone another website (e.g. https://www.usatoday.com/). Of course this only works when the site is requested via HTTPS (as Google [prefers secure origins](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/prefer-secure-origins-for-powerful-new-features)).

Now when I have another Website that simply loads the first one in an iFrame, Chrome only installs the Service Worker (in the secure iFrame) when the other site is requested over HTTPS as well.

Please compare

http://nameless-beef-plate-995.app.baqend.com/

and

https://nameless-beef-plate-995.app.baqend.com/

You should see

1. that the first link displays the iFrame with an orange background and an input field, which is the actual html on this domain (because the Service Worker could not be registed).
2. For the second url however you should see a clone of https://www.usatoday.com/.

In Firefox the Service Worker is installed in both cases and the cloning works as expected.

Does anyone know if this is intended behaviour? After all the Service Worker scope is restricted to the secure iFrame.

I am using Chrome 60.0.3112.50 on OSX and Firefox 54.0

-------------- EDIT --------------

Just realized: the Firefox does not install the Service Worker either! It just looked that way because it was installed before when I browsed the website https://makefast-staging.app.baqend.com/ in Firefox.

The the only difference to Chrome that remains is: Firefox executes the Service Worker when it was installed before in the iFrame (even for http://nameless-beef-plate-995.app.baqend.com/) but Chrome doesn't!

Now it looks more like a Bug in Firefox.